# How to get MySQL query process id executed by PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Is there a way to get the query process id that just issued by PHP mysqli_query or PDO?

sample..

```
$result = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM table");
```

And I want to get the process id of that specific query. If anyone here has ideas on how to solve this I would really appreciate it.. THank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean with "process id", but if you want to get the thread id of the currect mysql connection, you can do this with:

**MySQLi Object orientated style:**

```
/* MySQL thread id */
$thread_id = $mysqli->thread_id;

/* Kill connection */
$mysqli->kill($thread_id);
```

**MySQLi procedural style:**

```
/* MySQL thread id */
$thread_id = mysqli_thread_id($mysqli);

/* Kill connection */
mysqli_kill($mysqli, $thread_id);
```

**Using MySQL to get the thread ID in general:**

```
$query = "SELECT CONNECTION_ID()";
```

It's not like every query has its own "process". Every *connection* has. As long as you don't close the connection, the thread id will remain the same for each query.

Comment: Can I continuously check based on the Thread Id if the query takes time to finish? My goal is to kill the running query if it takes too long...

Comment: @victor I'm not formilliar with unix capabilities enough to know if that's possible or not. As far as I know, it's not possible to check if a query is still running. You can only check if it's succesfull. You could build in a timer with [usleep()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usleep.php) that delays PHP execution time after firing up the query and just kill the thread id after x amount of seconds.

Comment: @victor No problem! Good luck and happy coding :)